# Browser links become unresponsive while running Tomcat for several hours

Tags: windows-7, browser, hyperlink, tomcat

Please bear with me - this problem is somewhat unusual and a bit tricky to describe.  My system is Windows 7-64 and I'm running Tomcat 6.0.29.

I run two instances of Tomcat while I am developing on a project.  It works fine for the first 6 or 8 hours.  At various points, I will stop and Tomcat.  If it's left running for "long enough" - a span of time anywhere from 4 to ~10 hours - my browser will become unresponsive to clicking links.  I can open a new tab and type a URL or click a bookmark, and nothing happens.  I can click links and the browser ignores the click.  I can still scroll around and highlight text as if things were normal, but for whatever reason, you can't load anything new into the browser.

Restarting both instances of Tomcat doesn't fix it once it starts.  Restarting the browser or running a different browser has no effect.  And finally, logging off and logging on again helps a little - you get a few pages to load, with missing CSS or images, and then it happens again - no response.  The only remedy is to reboot.

This wouldn't be a huge problem except that I work remotely sometimes, and rebooting requires a physical presence at my PC because of McAfee Endpoint software that requires somebody at the keyboard log in before boot.  I have to find one of a few people on the phone who are able to log in for help.

I have a co-worker on the same project with the same problem.  We would both really appreciate any help or suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I hadn't changed *all* the ports to make sure the two tomcat instances were conflict-free.  Port 8080 and 8005 were set to be different, but the secure port 8443 and 8009 hadn't been changed to avoid conflicts.  Ever since I changed these, the system's been well behaved.